# How to make multiple HTTP calls in tabbed activity that hosts several fragments?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Since I got my teeth kicked in last time with the downvotes, I will make sure my question gets through better this time.

HomeActivity.java

```
    private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                return new ThisIsMyFirstFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ThisIsMySecondFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now when the Homeactivity gets created the position is obvioously at 1 and my "FirstFragment" does a Retrofit call and displays data in a recyclerView accordingly. So good so far.

However when I swipe to my "SecondFragment", which is basically the same although some modification to the list_item.xml, I get

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

I tried putting a Toast in my SecondFragment just for debugging purposes and realized that the Toast message gets shown everytime the onCreate gets called in HomeActivity. Am I missing something here?

```
SecondFragment.java
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news,container,false);

    mPresenter = new NewsPresenter(this);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_recyclerview);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    getNewsFeed();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void getNewsFeed() {

    mPresenter.getNews().enqueue(new Callback<DocumentResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DocumentResponse> call, Response<DocumentResponse> 

            MyResponseModel model = response.body();
            myList = model .getSomeStuff();
            mAdapter = new myAdapter(myList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DocumentResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

}
```

tl;dr
**How do you handle multiple http calls in a tabbed activity at the same time?**

Comment: You need to add some more code. is `mPresenter` shared across fragments? (hope not…), don’t put your view pager adapter inside the Activity. Either separate it to its own class or use a private static class. The “no adapter attached” is because you have a Recycler View `mRecyclerView` with no adapter (until the onResponse is called). Instead you should have the adapter work correctly with a null/empty list and accept a new list of items. Bonus points if you use `DiffUtil`. (See https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#diffing-larger-changes).

Comment: `Now when the Homeactivity gets created the position is obvioously at 1 ` -> not really, it’s at `0` ;)

Comment: tl;dr: the “multiple http calls” and “tabbed” activity have nothing to do with each other. Each “screen” (think Fragment in your case), must deal/ask its own presenter: “give me data to present when you can, I’ll wait”. The presenter will either make a request or use a “data interactor/repository” to make the http call. The presenter exposes a RXJava callback or similar, as far as I can see, but all that code, should live in the presenter. The presenter should later call the “fragment/view” back and tell it: “view.displayListOfWhatever(list);`. That’s the MVP approach.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini got it

Comment: @MartinMarconcini since I'm over you being snotty I should ask you since I'm kinda figuring the whole mvp thing out - in other words, sharing a presenter across all fragments but still within the host activity, is that not cool or what? second - what should I return from the presenter to send the view after the request has been done? I have no reference to my views in my presenter(?)

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `PagerAdapter` it's obviously that you see that `Toast` because adapter is creating +/-1 fragment from current position. In your case, when you create adapter for first time, is created  `ThisIsMyFirstFragment` and then `ThisIsMySecondFragment`. That's how is working `PagerAdapter` for faster user experience. If you had 3 fragments and you create for first time the adapter, you get created first and the second fragment. When you move to second fragment, first fragment is still there, second fragment was created previously and then is created third fragment. In this case, you have created 3 fragments, but is displayed just current position.

In your case, if you got `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout` it probably because you don't get any data from network. Use debuger to see if you get data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's helpful, I'll look into it